# MassTransit RespondAsync() throws Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus.MessagingEntityNotFoundException

Tags: azure-functions, azureservicebus, masstransit

A Web API with the following Startup configuration:

```
services.AddMassTransit(
 x =>
 {
    x.AddBus(provider => this.CreateBus(provider));
    string queueName = settings.InputQueueName;
    var serviceBusUri = new Uri($"{settings.ServiceBusUri}/{queueName}");
    CommandEndpointConvention.MapAll(serviceBusUri);
    x.AddRequestClient<CreateThingCommand>(serviceBusUri);
});
```

Injects the request client into the controller:

```
IRequestClient<CreateThingCommand> requestClient;
```

..constructs a command and puts the command on the Azure Service Bus and awaits the reponse:

```
var busResponse = await this.requestClient.GetResponse<CommandResponse>(command);
```

An Azure Function is triggered and handles the request, then calls `RespondAsync`

```
 await context.RespondAsync(response);
```

Every time, the `RespondAsync` line throws the following Exception.

```
Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus.MessagingEntityNotFoundException: 'Put token failed. status-code: 404, status-description: The messaging entity 'sb://dev-xxxxx-bus.servicebus.windows.net/DESKTOPXXYYZZ_iisexpress_bus_xrsyyydbnyyx9a4pbdcxkg6udd' could not be found. To know more visit https://aka.ms/sbResourceMgrExceptions
```

I expected the response message to be put on the `input-queue` and delivered to the caller.

What am I doing wrong?

There are some values of `context` on the `RespondAsync` line

[image]

I haven't been able to observe the creation of the temporary queue in Service Bus Explorer.

[image]

After the `MessagingEntityNotFoundException` is thrown, the `GetResponse` call eventually times out after 30 seconds, indicating that it is still running, in scope and listening.

Answer (score 1):

When using the request client, the responseAddress is set to the address of the bus endpoint, which is a temporary, auto-delete queue. The request client connects response/fault handlers to the bus endpoint dynamically as requests are sent, and disconnects those handlers after `GetResponse` completes.

Another point, you can easily create destination addresses for your service endpoints by using [short addresses](https://masstransit-project.com/usage/producers.html#short-addresses). For example:

```csharp
x.AddRequestClient<CreateThingCommand>(new Uri($"queue:{queueName}"));
```

If `RespondAsync` throws an `EntityNotFoundException` then it is safe to say that the original request client is no longer connected/listening for a response.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. After the `MessagingEntityNotFoundException` is thrown and execution continues, the `GetResponse` call times out after 30 seconds, which indicates that the request client is still in scope and listening.

I have ServiceBusExplorer open and at no point have I observed a temporary queue being created. Its like the Queue is not created at all.

Comment: Updated the question with a screenshot of Service Bus Explorer.

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget to start the bus!

`bus.StartAsync();`

> MassTransit uses a temporary non-durable queue and has a consumer to
> handle responses. This temporary queue only get configured and created
> when you start the bus. If you forget to start the bus in your
> application code, the request client will fail with a timeout, waiting
> for a response.

https://masstransit-project.com/troubleshooting/common-gotchas.html

In my case, not starting the bus wasn't stopping the `input-queue` from being created but was causing the temporary, auto-delete **reponse** queues to not be created.

Thaks @Chris Patterson for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: Ah, yes. Or use `AddMassTransitHostedService` to do it for you :)

Comment: It sounds like your AddMassTransitForAzureFunctions is working as expected though, which is good.